# zxing not detecting barcode. Possible width/height issue?

Tags: android, kotlin, zxing

I can't get my zxing QR scanner to detect QR codes. I've tested the following on the emulator and a Huawei P20.

I have assumed my QR code is OK as I've installed the zxing barcode scanner app on my phone and it detects it fine.

I have my camera previewer running fine and the callback is called fine. Just the detection seems not to detect anything. I've tried using the layout frame size and also the preview size, you can see what their values were in the code comments. I wonder if I'm getting the width/height wrong.

From my activity...

```
override fun onPreviewFrame(data: ByteArray, camera: Camera) {

    val length = data.size // 1382400
    val previewFormat = camera.parameters.previewFormat // 17 or 0x11 = NV21

    try {
// Tried this initially
//            val size = camera.parameters.previewSize
//            val width = size.width // 320
//            val height = size.height // 240

        val previewFrame : FrameLayout = findViewById(R.id.camera_preview)
        val width = previewFrame.width // 1100
        val height = previewFrame.height // 825

        val source = PlanarYUVLuminanceSource(data, width, height, 0, 0, width, height, false)
        val bitmap = BinaryBitmap(HybridBinarizer(source))
        val result = mQrReader.decodeWithState(bitmap)

// Never gets here

        qrList.add(result)
        adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
    } catch (nfe: NotFoundException) {
            // continue
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error: ${e.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    } finally {
        mQrReader.reset()
        camera.setOneShotPreviewCallback(this)
    }
}
```

From my layout...

```
    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
            android:layout_width="400dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp" />
```

Gradle...

```
implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.3.3'
```

In another SO post Sean Owen mentions not changing the format. I gave it a quick go anyway indesperation...

```
            mCamera!!.parameters.previewFormat = YUV_420_888
```

but that throws `Invalid pixel_format=35` exception when opening the camera.